# Pre-Login Handshake Timeout

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm getting the following error at a client's site when running SQL operations through a .NET library. As common a question as this is, the operations run perfectly 95% of the time. However, it seems that, on a daily basis at around 2.30am, I get the following error:

```
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.)
```

My application then ceases to operate until it is completely stopped and restarted. As this requires manual intervention, the application does nothing for about 6 hours. My SQL connection string looks as follows:

```
Data Source=<SERVER>;Initial Catalog=<CATALOG>;User ID=<UN>;Password=<PW>
```

Running **netsh winsock show catalog** shows no problems - it seems strange that I can run the software perfectly fine during the day and only at night do these problems occur. Any ideas as to what is going on?

Comment: If you **[search Google for your error message](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=A+connection+was+successfully+established+with+the+server%2C+but+then+an+error+occurred+during+the+pre-login+handshake.+%28provider%3A+SSL+Provider%2C+error%3A+0+-+The+wait+operation+timed+out)** there is a plethora of pages giving information on this problem. I think the best start would be to read these, try the proposed solutions, then if these don't work edit your question to show what you have tried. This will avoid people suggesting solutions that you have already tried without success.

Comment: There are also **[18 other Questions on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=A+connection+was+successfully+established+with+the+server%2C+but+then+an+error+occurred+during+the+pre-login+handshake.+%28provider%3A+SSL+Provider%2C+error%3A+0+-+The+wait+operation+timed+out.%29)** that contain this error message. Have you tried the solutions in any of these?

Answer (score 0):

Old thread here, but since I could not find a lot around this specific topic I will share what solved it for me so it can be useful for someone else.

I needed to increase the timeout on the connection string, since when connecting by vpn it took to long to establish the connection. You can do this by adding ;connection timeout = value

By default the timeout is set to 15 seconds.